# How to pass string only rather than the entire event in the onchange?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hi I am now working on a project. There were 2 component inside.
`InputDialog` & `AuthenComponent`.
I am now trying to keep track of the string inside the `HTMLTextAreaElement`.
My way of doing thing is working fine but one of the senior want a different way.
I will now show you the working version.

`InputDialog` Component

```
interface InputDialogContentProps {
  onChange: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => string;
}

export default function InputDialog(props: InputDialogContentProps) {
  return (
    <div className="inputDialogContent">
      <DialogContent className="dialogContentPlacement">
        <TextField
          onChange={props.onChange}
          fullWidth
        />
      </DialogContent>
    </div>
  );
}
```

as you can see I am getting the `onchange event` from the props.

This is the AuthenComponent ( Function component )

```
<Dialog
    open
    onClose={hideDialogBox}
    aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
    aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
    className="TextPlacement"
>
 <div className="AuthenticationDialog">

  <InputDialogContent
     inputLabel="Email Address"
     inputType="email"
     onChange={onInputChange}/>
   </div>
  </Dialog>

function onInputChange(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) {
    setEnableLoginButton(isValidEmail(e.target.value));
    return e.target.value;
  }

const isValidEmail = (email: string): boolean => {
  const validateFormat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+$/;
  return email.match(validateFormat);
};
```

These component are working fine. But senior want me to pass the string only rather than passing the entire event. I have been searching google for too long and can't find a soluton.

He want something like this in `inputDialog`

```
onChange: (text: string) => void
```

Rather than

```
onChange: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => string;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the value from the element inside the child component's handler, and call the prop function with it:

```
interface InputDialogContentProps {
  checkValidEmail: (text: string) => void
}
```

```
onChange={(e) => { props.checkValidEmail(e.currentTarget.value); }}
```

And in the parent component:

```
function checkValidEmail(text: string) {
  setEnableLoginButton(isValidEmail(text));
}
```

Comment: how to keep track of the text inside the textArea?
in the parent element `<InputDialogContent  onChange={checkValidEmail}/>` is not working

Comment: You need to change the prop name to `checkValidEmail` - it's not exactly the change handler anymore. `<InputDialogContent checkValidEmail={checkValidEmail}`

Comment: Thanks, you forget `props` for this line `onChange={(e) => { checkValidEmail(e.currentTarget.value); }}` 
Thank you for your help

Comment: Hi 
its not really related but
Is there any advantages in using string ? instead of passing the entire event .
or it was just a different way of doing things. can you send me a link to an article related to this. I don't know how to search this topic

Comment: It can make the typings easier and more controlled. The parent component doesn't really care about how the child component receives the user's input, so it makes a bit more sense to leave it to the child. Imagine if you had *other* child components which did something similar, except some had `inputs` instead of textures, or maybe something completely different. Better to leave those details to the child that's implementing them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<InputDialogContent
 inputLabel="Email Address"
 inputType="email"
 onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e.target.value)}/>
```

then your `onInputChange` function

```
function onInputChange(email: string) {
   setEnableLoginButton(isValidEmail(email));
   return email;
}
```

Comment: How about this line `onChange: (text: string) => void` inside the InputDialog component